# set a row to perform a function on another row

Tags: sqlite

Is it at all possible to do something like the following:

```
create table t1(
       t1_id integer primary key,
       a integer);

create table t2(
       t2_id integer primary key,
       b integer);

create table t3(
       t1_id integer primary key,
       c integer t(a) + t(b));
```

where a row in a table performs a simple function on one or more other rows (either in the same table or as shown above), that would automatically update itself when changes occur? a couple of hours of googling and I still find myself none the wiser.

Comment: Rows in a database do not “perform” any “function”, they just hold data. Maybe you are looking for VIEWs? http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html

Comment: @CBroe I think that might be exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was looking for something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW ab AS SELECT t1.a + t2.b FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.t1_id = t2.t2_id
```